# Edit and save XML adding extra [] characters

Tags: c#, xml

I have a requirement to edit and save- precisely replace a text in an xml (within the c# project) with a value from arguments and save in temp location. The value is replaced and saved in location, but it adds some characters- [] and hence when i use the xml in another application as input, it is shown as incorrect xml! Even when i remove the extra character and save and rerun it shows the same error. However when i remove the extra character and paste the whole xml into a new file it works fine! I dont understand whats the issue. Have pasted my code below:

```
{
parameterFileName = "test";

tempPath = Path.GetTempPath() + parameterFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xml";

XmlDocument xdoc = GetParameterXML(parameterFileName);
            XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

            XmlNode node = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"/root/inputParameters");
            XmlNode childNode = node.ChildNodes[0];
            if (childNode is XmlCDataSection)
            {
                XmlCDataSection cdataSection = childNode as XmlCDataSection;

                if (cdataSection.Value.Contains("ID_VALUE"))
                {
                    cdataSection.Value = cdataSection.Value.Replace("ID_VALUE", id);
                }
            }


 xdoc.Save(tempPath);
}



public static XmlDocument GetParameterXML(string parameterFileName)
    {
        var sDllPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(sDllPath + "\\Templates\\" + parameterFileName + ".xml");
        return xDoc;
    }
```

Comment: show your xml please?

Comment: The part of output xml file with characters:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "Parameters.dtd"[]>

The part of input (no replacement occurs here- its within a cdata section):
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "Parameters.dtd">

Comment: I added answer below try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you parse Xml Document by using `XmlDocument` with DTD then empty Internal Subset means Square Brackets [] is automatically inserted.

```
public static XmlDocument GetParameterXML(string parameterFileName)
{
    var sDllPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(sDllPath + "\\Templates\\" + parameterFileName + ".xml");

    if (xDoc.DocumentType != null)
    {
        var name = xDoc.DocumentType.Name;
        var publicId = xDoc.DocumentType.PublicId;
        var systemId = xDoc.DocumentType.SystemId;
        var parent = xDoc.DocumentType.ParentNode;
        var documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset = xDoc.CreateDocumentType(name, publicId, systemId, null);
        parent.ReplaceChild(documentTypeWithNullInternalSubset, xDoc.DocumentType);
    }

    return xDoc;
}
```

**Does it matter?**

No this does not matter. but its a well formed XML if your XML doesn't contain any internal subset then it represent as blank square brackets []. it means that your xml doesn't contain any internal subset.

While parsing xml with XDocument with no internal subset then XDocument append blank square brackets [] instead of display nothing in DOCTYPE.

**What does an empty internal subset do?**

The basic purpose of an internal entity is to get rid of typing same content (like the name of the organization) again and again. And instead, we can define an internal entity to contain the text and then only you need to use the entity where you want to insert the text. Because the entity is expanded by the parser, you can be assured that you'll get the same text in every location. The parser will also catch if you misspell an entity name.

You can read more about Internal Subset [here](https://www.w3resource.com/xml/internal-entities.php)

Comment: xdoc.DocumentType.InternalSubset = null; 
this is not possible as xdoc.DocumentType.InternalSubset is ReadOnly :(

Comment: Property or indexer 'XmlDocumentType.InternalSubset' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: `InternalSubset ` property have get and set so you can easily overrite it

Comment: Show me how did you implement this

Comment: see screen shot  in **Edit** section its have Get and Set both

Comment: Ok so the difference is what i have is XmlDocument and in the screenshot it is XDocument

Comment: ohh. got it, wait I'll update my answer for XmlDocument

Comment: Thanks...now the character has gone. but stillwhile uploading the xml i get invalid xml file error and when i copy the same contents and create a new file and upload it works fine... So wierd.. wat would be the issue in the first save?( For the background information- I am actually working on 3d experience and trying to run a Catutil batch monitor job from code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187663/discussion-between-er-mfahhgk-and-sina123).

Comment: What happened did you try my answer and does it solved your problem?

Comment: No the problem still persists :( Actually as you said theres an issue while saving the xml doc as i just tried to save an xml and input it to server it shows error. So I am not sure what to do but i want to save the xml!

Comment: If you think there is no problem then, I'll take a remote access via AnyDesk or TeamViewer for your pc tomorrow and then try to resolve problem. So ping me tomorrow then we'll proceed :)